# random numbers 1-10 without repeating. Why does this code not work. It compiles but still repeats

Tags: java

This code repeats numbers and with the if statement I wrote in I don't think it should

```
class RandomNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int[] q = new int[10];

    while(y != q.length) {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

            if (x != q[0] || x != q[1] || x != q[2] || x != q[3] || x != q[4] || x != q[5]
            || x != q[6] || x != q[7] || x != q[8] || x != q[9]) {
                q[z] = x;
                System.out.println(q[z]);   // or you could print x it doesn't matter
                y++;                        // I just chose this one to make sure each
                z++;                        // q[] was getting set to a value

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why while(y != q.length)? Maybe while(y <= q.length)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AND and not OR in your condition, since x must be different then all elements in the array.

That said, you should note that the array would be initialized to 0s, so if `0` is one of the valid values you wish to have in the random array, the loop will never terminate.

I would check for duplicates only in the sub-array that was already initialized :

```
int z = 0;
while(z != q.length) {
    int x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    boolean isDup=false;
    for (int i=0;i<z&&!isDup;i++) {
        if (x==q[i])
            isDup=true;
    }
    if (!isDup) {
        q[z] = x;
        System.out.println(q[z]);                           
        z++;                       
    }
}
```

BTW, y and z are always the same, so you don't need them both.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Problem solved. And it's also more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x != q[0] || x != q[1] || x != q[2] || x != q[3] || x != q[4] || x != q[5]
        || x != q[6] || x != q[7] || x != q[8] || x != q[9])
```

It will be `false` always . so the your code inside `if` block is not executed